# Convert non-ASCII to character representations beginning with backslash u (\u) in R?

Tags: r, iconv

Running `R CMD check --as-cran` gives

```
Portable packages must use only ASCII characters in their R code,
except perhaps in comments.
Use \uxxxx escapes for other characters.
```

What are `\uxxxx`, and more importantly, how can I convert non ASCII characters into them?

#### What I know so far

- `?iconv` is very informative, and looks powerful, but I see nothing of the form `\u`
- [this](https://docs.python.org/2.2/ref/strings.html) python documentation indicates `\uxxxx` are

> Character with 16-bit hex value xxxx (Unicode only)

#### Question

How can I convert non-ASCII characters into character representations of the form `\uxxxx`

Some examples `c("¤", "£", "€", "¢", "¥", "₧", "ƒ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `stri_escape_unicode` from [stringi](https://github.com/gagolews/stringi) to escape unicode:

```
stringi::stri_escape_unicode(c("¤", "£", "€", "¢", "¥", "₧", "ƒ"))
## [1] "\\u00a4" "\\u00a3" "\\u20ac" "\\u00a2" "\\u00a5" "P"       "\\u0192"
```

I have an addin based on that to remove non ascii characters between quotes in function here : https://github.com/dreamRs/prefixer

Comment: Thanks so much! For the second last character, we see something a little different, I am not sure why? I see `[1] "\\u00a4" "\\u00a3" "\\u20ac" "\\u00a2" "\\u00a5" "\\u20a7" "\\u0192"`

Comment: I'm on Windows, that can explain it, or maybe the copy/paste from the HTML page...